# Error on my proxmox console when i want to do a get-update

Tags: linux, updates, apt

i wanted to do a get-update command but i get this error

```
E: Failed to fetch https://enterprise.proxmox.com/debian/ceph-quincy/dists/bookworm/InRelease  401  Unauthorized [IP: 51.91.38.34 443]
E: The repository 'https://enterprise.proxmox.com/debian/ceph-quincy bookworm InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://enterprise.proxmox.com/debian/pve/dists/bookworm/InRelease  401  Unauthorized [IP: 51.91.38.34 443]
E: The repository 'https://enterprise.proxmox.com/debian/pve bookworm InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: The error message seems to be clear. Would you like to use that repo anyway?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Proxmox/comments/jn7jpe/cant_apt_update/

Comment: https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/apt-update-upgrade-does-not-work.99294/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.